# Chrome won't start after update Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

After updating Chrome today, it fails to be launched. Any ideas on how to fix this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

I've already tried:

- deleting cookies;
- deleting and reinstalling;

Comment: What's the output when you run `google-chrome-stable` from a terminal?

Comment: `NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.`

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libnss3`

Comment: Already started it, let's hope that's the fix.

Comment: Fixed it, without having to use `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libnss3`.

Comment: What was the fix then?

Comment: Just running `sudo apt-get update`. Summarized it in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Running `google-chrome-stable` in the terminal gave me the following message: 
`NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer`

This was quite easily solved by just running:

`sudo apt-get update`.

As [Android Dev](https://askubuntu.com/users/518562/android-dev) suggested, running `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade libnss3` might also work.